# Highlight a single word that would be encountered after a specific word

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I want to highlight the next word encountered after a specific word (e.g.: "class"). In other terms, the next word after "class" should be highlighted with the highlight group that I would like.

I feel like I have to utilize the match command but I don't know how. So, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
hi ClassName guibg=#A0A0A0
match ClassName /\(class\s\+\)\@<=\w\+/
```

The regular expression `\(class\s\+\)\@<=\w\+` use `\@<=` that make the match only if the preceding predicate (i.e.: `\(class\s\+\)`) is matching but match with zero width such that `class` is not highlighted.

You could also do:

```
hi ClassName guibg=#A0A0A0
match ClassName /class\s\+\zs\w\+/
```

Comment: yoo thanks a lot man. you made my day.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). Welcome to Vim.

Comment: Hey I have another question if okay. When I'm forward declaring a class like `class Base;`, `Base` gets highlighted. Now, is there any way that this statement would spawn a process which would store the term `Base` in some kind of temporary storage so as a result, `Base` would end up getting highlighted throughout the entire file and the other files that includes this statement?

Comment: As of my knowledge this is not a functionality of Vim but it can probably be achieved using a Vim script. Feel free to ask another question maybe someone already has something like that or create it for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.